# Summarize values even they not exist in second table

Tags: mysql, join, sum

I have two tables. First one contains product codes, and second one product codes and quantities.

Now I want to summarize all quantites for each product code even there are not all products in second table. 
The output should be product code and total quantity of each code, and for codes that they don't have qty let it be 0.

```
**Table1** 
productName  |
--------------
     a       | 
     b       |  
     c       |  
     d       |
     e       |

**Table2**  
productName  | QTY   |
----------------------
     a       |   3   |  
     b       |   4   |
     a       |   1   |
     b       |   2   |
     c       |   1   |    

**Output**    
productName  | QTY   |
----------------------
     a       |   4   |  
     b       |   6   |
     c       |   1   |
     d       |       |
     e       |       |
```

```
SELECT tbl1.productname, SUM(tbl2.qty) AS TotQTY
FROM tbl1
INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.productname = tbl2.productname
group by tbl1.productname
```

Here is my try in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/619228/3)

I can only get records with quantites, but other are not displayed.

Comment: Sqlfiddle isn't working for me (just hanging), but sound like you need a LEFT OUTER JOIN

Comment: I don't know what's wrong today with sqlfiddle.. With LEFT OUTER JOIN it returns me only record that does not have qauntity.

Comment: Ah, SQLfiddle woke up. In SQLfiddle you have omitted the GROUP BY clause. You also have checked for _WHERE Table2.productName IS NULL_ , which will exclude any rows that do have a qty on table2.

Comment: Without GROUP BY i get total sum of all codes not for each of them, and i don't want to exclude rows without qty.

Comment: Yes, you NEED the GROUP BY clause. In SQLfiddle you have left it out which is why it sums up ALL codes. The WHERE clause you have used there IS excluding the rows with a quantity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Table1.productName,COALESCE(SUM(Table2.qty),0) AS TotQTY
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.productName = Table2.productName
group by Table1.productName
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT Table1.productName, SUM(Table2.qty)  AS TotQTY
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.productName = Table2.productName
group by Table1.productName
```

Comment: This works but only for codes that have quantities. I want to include all records. See in my first post what kind of output I want to have.

Comment: It is showing all the records. Please check it once.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be what you want:-

```
SELECT Table1.productName, COALESCE(SUM(Table2.qty),0) AS TotQTY
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.productName = Table2.productName
GROUP BY Table1.productname
```

SQLfiddle:-

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/619228/3